# Synchronizing two videos in JWPlayer (RTMP Streaming) - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I want to use 2 players synchronously. When I trigger the play in one, both run together!
Is there any way to when the User move the video forward or there is some buffer in a video, both videos still together?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Here is some quick basic example code that uses our JavaScript API to do this. Note, this uses 6.12 and uses HTML5, but the same should work with Flash/RTMP/JW7. This uses our JavaScript API - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sync</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player1"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="player2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player1").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
    });
    jwplayer("player2").setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4",
    });
    jwplayer("player1").onBeforePlay(function(){
        jwplayer("player2").play(); 
    });
    jwplayer("player2").onBeforePlay(function() { 
        jwplayer("player1").play(); 
    });
    jwplayer("player1").onPause(function(){
        if(jwplayer("player2").getState() == "PLAYING"){
            jwplayer("player2").pause();
        }
    });
    jwplayer("player2").onPause(function(){
        if(jwplayer("player1").getState() == "PLAYING"){
            jwplayer("player1").pause();
        }
    });
    jwplayer("player1").onSeek(function(e){
        jwplayer("player2").seek(e.offset);
    });
    jwplayer("player2").onSeek(function(e){
        jwplayer("player1").seek(e.offset);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update, here is an example of this working with one set of controls for both players:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sync</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left;"><div id="player1"></div></div>
    <div style="float:right;"><div id="player2"></div></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="jwplayer('player1').play();jwplayer('player2').play();">Play/Pause</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="jwplayer('player1').stop();jwplayer('player2').stop();">Stop</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="var position = jwplayer('player1').getPosition();position-=5;jwplayer('player1').seek(position);jwplayer('player2').seek(position);">Seek Back</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="var position2 = jwplayer('player1').getPosition();position2+=5;jwplayer('player1').seek(position2);jwplayer('player2').seek(position2);">Seek Ahead</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player1").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
        controls:false
    });
    jwplayer("player2").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
        controls:false
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, But the both player are not syncing with each other when I click on play, each player taking their own time to buffer video and then start video but both are not starting at same time.   I added you code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5tgq8gaf/

Comment: I would like to play same  video in multiple players and control all players with one player controls and they all would be sync with each other.

Comment: They both play and pause at the same time for me. What you could always do here is make some html links on a page that call jwplayer().play() for each player, for example, and do the same thing for pause, seek, stop, etc.

Comment: They are not syncing with each other. Play, pause, stop are working fine but after clicking on play button they are taking different-2 time for buffer video due to this they are not syncing with each other. In some other case, I took number of players with same video , they have not synchronization with each other due to different-2 time taken by them to buffer. Please review http://jsfiddle.net/5tgq8gaf/5/show/

Comment: Do you have the RTMP Streams set up? If so, you could use bufferlength to make them tame the same amount of time to buffer.

Comment: Yes, I set bufferlength to 0.1 but still getting same problem. :(

Comment: Do you have an example using RTMP?